# Is .ix() always better than .loc() and .iloc() since it is faster and supports integer and label access?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm learning the Python pandas library. Coming from an R background, the indexing and selecting functions seem more complicated than they need to be. My understanding it that .loc() is only label based and .iloc() is only integer based.

**Why should I ever use .loc() and .iloc() if .ix() is faster and supports integer and label access?**

Comment: This answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31593712/2303761) should be VERY helpful!

Comment: Never use **`.ix`**! [Here is an even more helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46915810/3707607) for the differences between `.loc`, `.iloc` and `[]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas iloc vs ix vs loc explanation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/pandas-iloc-vs-ix-vs-loc-explanation)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Please refer to the doc [Different Choices for Indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html), it states clearly when and why you should use **.loc, .iloc** over **.ix**, it's about explicit use case:

> .ix supports mixed integer and label based access. It is primarily
> label based, but will fall back to integer positional access unless
> the corresponding axis is of integer type. .ix is the most general and
> will support any of the inputs in .loc and .iloc. .ix also supports
> floating point label schemes. .ix is exceptionally useful when dealing
> with mixed positional and label based hierachical indexes.
>
> However, when an axis is integer based, ONLY label based access and
> not positional access is supported. Thus, in such cases, it’s usually
> better to be explicit and use .iloc or .loc.

#### Update 22 Mar 2017

Thanks to comment from @Alexander, **Pandas** is going to deprecate `ix` in **0.20**, details in [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20.1/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0200-api-breaking-deprecate-ix).

One of the strong reason behind is because mixing indexes -- positional and label (effectively using `ix`) has been a significant source of problems for users.

It is expected to migrate to use `iloc` and `loc` instead, here is a link on [how to convert code](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20.1/indexing.html#indexing-deprecate-ix).

Comment: can you clarify what the "However, when an axis is integer based, ONLY label based access and not positional access is supported. Thus, in such cases, it’s usually better to be explicit and use .iloc or .loc." means?  

That part is hazy for me

Comment: @AZhao, I don't think I understand what you want me to clarify, do you want to know the  differences between chioces of index or how to determine "explicit"? Perhaps you may read [Difference choices of indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing).

Comment: @AZhao, I think this means that if you use integers *as* your labels (which might not correspond to their column order), then it won't be able to differentiate which one you mean. Someone correct me if I'm misinterpreting.

Comment: It appears that the `.ix` indexer will be deprecated in Pandas 0.20.0 http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#deprecate-ix

Comment: @Alexander - thanks for the deprecation note, I will update the answer to reflect this :)

Answer (score 0):

`DataFrame.ix` has been completely removed since Pandas 1.0.0 released in January 2020, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html#removal-of-prior-version-deprecations-changes