# pandas loc vs. iloc vs. at vs. iat?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, indexing, lookup

Recently began branching out from my safe place (R) into Python and and am a bit confused by the cell localization/selection in `Pandas`. I've read the documentation but I'm struggling to understand the practical implications of the various localization/selection options.

Is there a reason why I should ever use `.loc` or `.iloc` over `at`, and `iat` or vice versa?  **In what situations should I use which method?**

---

> <sub>Note: future readers be aware that this question is old and was written before pandas v0.20 when there used to exist a function called `.ix`. This method was later split into two - `loc` and `iloc` - to make the explicit distinction between positional and label based indexing. Please beware that `ix` was discontinued due to inconsistent behavior and being hard to grok, and no longer exists in current versions of pandas (>= 1.0).</sub>

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27667759/is-ix-always-better-than-loc-and-iloc-since-it-is-faster-and-supports-i?rq=1

Comment: `loc` is label based indexing so basically looking up a value in a row, `iloc` is integer row based indexing, `ix` is a general method that first performs label based, if that fails then it falls to integer based. `at` is deprecated and it's advised you don't use that anymore. The other thing to consider is what you are trying to do as some of these methods allow slicing, and column assignment, to be honest the docs are pretty clear: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

Comment: @EdChum - what makes you say that `at` is deprecated?  I don't see it in the [at](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html?highlight=#pandas.DataFrame.at) (or [iat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html?highlight=#pandas.DataFrame.iat)) docs.

Comment: That's an error it's not deprecated, I think there was some talk of deprecating it but this idea was dropped because I think it's faster

Comment: Detail explanation between `loc`, `ix` and `iloc` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/pandas-iloc-vs-ix-vs-loc-explanation/31593712#31593712

Comment: [See the extremely detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47098873/3707607) with DataFrame images below

Answer (score 195, accepted):

**loc:** only work on index
**iloc:** work on position
**at:** get scalar values. It's a very fast loc
**iat:** Get scalar values. It's a very fast iloc

Also,

> `at` and `iat` are meant to access a scalar, that is, a single element
> in the dataframe, while `loc` and `iloc` are ments to access several
> elements at the same time, potentially to perform vectorized
> operations.

http://pyciencia.blogspot.com/2015/05/obtener-y-filtrar-datos-de-un-dataframe.html

Comment: If `at` and `iat` are very fast versions of `loc` and `iloc`, then why use `loc` and `iloc` at all?

Comment: `at`and `iat` a meant to access a scalar, that is, a single element in the dataframe, while `loc` and `iloc`are ments to access several elements at the same time, potentially to perform vectorized operations.

Comment: @ncasas - if I read the documentation right .at can only access by index while .loc can also access by column name. Is there a way to use the faster .at but use the column name instead of an index?
Like replacing x=df.loc[df.Id == source_Id, 'someValue'].values[0] with x=df.at[df.Id == source_Id, 'someValue']. Version with .at throws "ValueError: At based indexing on an integer index can only have integer indexers"

Comment: `.values[]` is faster than `.iat`

Comment: I know what an *index* is. For example, if you have a list of 100 items maybe `item[15]` is the sixteenth item. However, what is the difference between an "index" and a "position" Saying that `loc` takes "indicies" as input and that `iloc` accepts "positions" as input is confusing. A "position" is difference from an "index" in what way exactly?

Comment: @Gerenuk .values[] access a single element or can it access several elements (a subset) at a time?

Comment: @HighGPA .values will return a plain Numpy array. So yes, you can access several elements as you would do with numpy array.

Comment: @Gerenuk .iat can be used to assign values to a df. Can the .values[] also be used this way?

Comment: @HighGPA Surprisingly, it can be used to assign values, because it probably exposes the internal underlying numpy array. Not sure if there is an edge case where pandas discards modifications to that array.

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon if you have 4 items in a Pandas object, your index might be `['a', 'b', 'plum', 'hotdog']`, but your position (what `iloc` and `iat` use) will always be `[0, 1, 2, 3]`.

Answer (score 134):

Updated for `pandas` `0.20` given that `ix` is deprecated.  This demonstrates not only how to use `loc`, `iloc`, `at`, `iat`, `set_value`, but how to accomplish, mixed positional/label based indexing.

---

[**`loc`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) - **label based**
Allows you to pass 1-D arrays as indexers.  Arrays can be either slices (subsets) of the index or column, or they can be boolean arrays which are equal in length to the index or columns.

**Special Note:** when a scalar indexer is passed, `loc` can assign a new index or column value that didn't exist before.

```
# label based, but we can use position values
# to get the labels from the index object
df.loc[df.index[2], 'ColName'] = 3
```

---

```
df.loc[df.index[1:3], 'ColName'] = 3
```

---

[**`iloc`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) - **position based**
Similar to `loc` except with positions rather that index values.  However, you **cannot** assign new columns or indices.

```
# position based, but we can get the position
# from the columns object via the `get_loc` method
df.iloc[2, df.columns.get_loc('ColName')] = 3
```

---

```
df.iloc[2, 4] = 3
```

---

```
df.iloc[:3, 2:4] = 3
```

---

[**`at`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) - **label based**
Works very similar to `loc` for scalar indexers.  **Cannot** operate on array indexers.  **Can!** assign new indices and columns.

**Advantage** over `loc` is that this is faster.
**Disadvantage** is that you can't use arrays for indexers.

```
# label based, but we can use position values
# to get the labels from the index object
df.at[df.index[2], 'ColName'] = 3
```

---

```
df.at['C', 'ColName'] = 3
```

---

[**`iat`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html) - **position based**
Works similarly to `iloc`.  **Cannot** work in array indexers.  **Cannot!** assign new indices and columns.

**Advantage** over `iloc` is that this is faster.
**Disadvantage** is that you can't use arrays for indexers.

```
# position based, but we can get the position
# from the columns object via the `get_loc` method
IBM.iat[2, IBM.columns.get_loc('PNL')] = 3
```

---

[**`set_value`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_value.html) - **label based**
Works very similar to `loc` for scalar indexers.  **Cannot** operate on array indexers.  **Can!** assign new indices and columns

**Advantage** Super fast, because there is very little overhead!
**Disadvantage** There is very little overhead because `pandas` is not doing a bunch of safety checks.  ***Use at your own risk***.  Also, this is not intended for public use.

```
# label based, but we can use position values
# to get the labels from the index object
df.set_value(df.index[2], 'ColName', 3)
```

---

[**`set_value` with `takable=True`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_value.html) - **position based**
Works similarly to `iloc`.  **Cannot** work in array indexers.  **Cannot!** assign new indices and columns.

**Advantage** Super fast, because there is very little overhead!
**Disadvantage** There is very little overhead because `pandas` is not doing a bunch of safety checks.  ***Use at your own risk***.  Also, this is not intended for public use.

```
# position based, but we can get the position
# from the columns object via the `get_loc` method
df.set_value(2, df.columns.get_loc('ColName'), 3, takable=True)
```

Comment: So, is there a simple way to read/set multiple columns by position? Further, say, I wanted to add an array of values each into new columns, is this easily done?

Comment: @wordsmith there are easy ish ways to append new columns to the end of the dataframe. Or even the beginning. If the positions are involved then no, there isn't an easy way.

Comment: This answer was just what I needed! Pandas is certainly powerful, but that comes at the expense of making everything extremely complicated to understand and piece together.

Comment: Note that `set_value` has been deprecated in favour of `.at` and `.iat` since version 0.21

Comment: reason for not being able to assign new indexes or columns should be clear; without a column or index name, the function cannot create the index or the column. So with label bases, the functions have the necessary information to create a new index or column.

Answer (score 90):

There are two primary ways that pandas makes selections from a DataFrame.

- By **Label**
- By **Integer Location**

The documentation uses the term **position** for referring to **integer location**. I do not like this terminology as I feel it is confusing. Integer location is more descriptive and is exactly what `.iloc` stands for. The key word here is **INTEGER** - you must use integers when selecting by integer location.

Before showing the summary let's all make sure that ...

## .ix is deprecated and ambiguous and should never be used

There are three primary **indexers** for pandas. We have the indexing operator itself (the brackets **`[]`**), **`.loc`**, and **`.iloc`**. Let's summarize them:

- **`[]`** - Primarily selects subsets of columns, but can select rows as well. Cannot simultaneously select rows and columns.
- **`.loc`** - selects subsets of rows and columns by label only
- **`.iloc`** - selects subsets of rows and columns by integer location only

I almost never use **`.at`** or **`.iat`** as they add no additional functionality and with just a small performance increase. I would discourage their use unless you have a very time-sensitive application. Regardless, we have their summary:

- **`.at`** selects a single scalar value in the DataFrame by label only
- **`.iat`** selects a single scalar value in the DataFrame by integer location only

In addition to selection by label and integer location, **boolean selection** also known as **boolean indexing** exists.

---

#### Examples explaining `.loc`, `.iloc`, boolean selection and `.at` and `.iat` are shown below

We will first focus on the differences between `.loc` and `.iloc`. Before we talk about the differences, it is important to understand that DataFrames have labels that help identify each column and each row. Let's take a look at a sample DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'age':[30, 2, 12, 4, 32, 33, 69],
                   'color':['blue', 'green', 'red', 'white', 'gray', 'black', 'red'],
                   'food':['Steak', 'Lamb', 'Mango', 'Apple', 'Cheese', 'Melon', 'Beans'],
                   'height':[165, 70, 120, 80, 180, 172, 150],
                   'score':[4.6, 8.3, 9.0, 3.3, 1.8, 9.5, 2.2],
                   'state':['NY', 'TX', 'FL', 'AL', 'AK', 'TX', 'TX']
                   },
                  index=['Jane', 'Nick', 'Aaron', 'Penelope', 'Dean', 'Christina', 'Cornelia'])
```

[image]

All the words in **bold** are the labels. The labels, `age`, `color`, `food`, `height`, `score` and `state` are used for the **columns**. The other labels, `Jane`, `Nick`, `Aaron`, `Penelope`, `Dean`, `Christina`, `Cornelia` are used as labels for the rows. Collectively, these row labels are known as the **index**.

---

The primary ways to select particular rows in a DataFrame are with the `.loc` and `.iloc` indexers. Each of these indexers can also be used to simultaneously select columns but it is easier to just focus on rows for now. Also, each of the indexers use a set of brackets that immediately follow their name to make their selections.

### .loc selects data only by labels

We will first talk about the `.loc` indexer which only selects data by the index or column labels. In our sample DataFrame, we have provided meaningful names as values for the index. Many DataFrames will not have any meaningful names and will instead, default to just the integers from 0 to n-1, where n is the length(number of rows) of the DataFrame.

There are [many different inputs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) you can use for `.loc` three out of them are

- A string
- A list of strings
- Slice notation using strings as the start and stop values

**Selecting a single row with .loc with a string**

To select a single row of data, place the index label inside of the brackets following `.loc`.

```
df.loc['Penelope']
```

This returns the row of data as a Series

```
age           4
color     white
food      Apple
height       80
score       3.3
state        AL
Name: Penelope, dtype: object
```

**Selecting multiple rows with .loc with a list of strings**

```
df.loc[['Cornelia', 'Jane', 'Dean']]
```

This returns a DataFrame with the rows in the order specified in the list:

[image]

**Selecting multiple rows with .loc with slice notation**

Slice notation is defined by a start, stop and step values. When slicing by label, pandas includes the stop value in the return. The following slices from Aaron to Dean, inclusive. Its step size is not explicitly defined but defaulted to 1.

```
df.loc['Aaron':'Dean']
```

[image]

Complex slices can be taken in the same manner as Python lists.

### .iloc selects data only by integer location

Let's now turn to `.iloc`. Every row and column of data in a DataFrame has an integer location that defines it. This is in addition to the label that is visually displayed in the output. The integer location is simply the number of rows/columns from the top/left beginning at 0.

There are [many different inputs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) you can use for `.iloc` three out of them are

- An integer
- A list of integers
- Slice notation using integers as the start and stop values

**Selecting a single row with .iloc with an integer**

```
df.iloc[4]
```

This returns the 5th row (integer location 4) as a Series

```
age           32
color       gray
food      Cheese
height       180
score        1.8
state         AK
Name: Dean, dtype: object
```

**Selecting multiple rows with .iloc with a list of integers**

```
df.iloc[[2, -2]]
```

This returns a DataFrame of the third and second to last rows:

[image]

**Selecting multiple rows with .iloc with slice notation**

```
df.iloc[:5:3]
```

[image]

---

### Simultaneous selection of rows and columns with .loc and .iloc

One excellent ability of both `.loc/.iloc` is their ability to select both rows and columns simultaneously. In the examples above, all the columns were returned from each selection. We can choose columns with the same types of inputs as we do for rows. We simply need to separate the row and column selection with a **comma**.

For example, we can select rows Jane, and Dean with just the columns height, score and state like this:

```
df.loc[['Jane', 'Dean'], 'height':]
```

[image]

This uses a list of labels for the rows and slice notation for the columns

We can naturally do similar operations with `.iloc` using only integers.

```
df.iloc[[1,4], 2]
Nick      Lamb
Dean    Cheese
Name: food, dtype: object
```

---

#### Simultaneous selection with labels and integer location

`.ix` was used to make selections simultaneously with labels and integer location which was useful but confusing and ambiguous at times and thankfully it has been deprecated. In the event that you need to make a selection with a mix of labels and integer locations, you will have to make both your selections labels or integer locations.

For instance, if we want to select rows `Nick` and `Cornelia` along with columns 2 and 4, we could use `.loc` by converting the integers to labels with the following:

```
col_names = df.columns[[2, 4]]
df.loc[['Nick', 'Cornelia'], col_names]
```

Or alternatively, convert the index labels to integers with the `get_loc` index method.

```
labels = ['Nick', 'Cornelia']
index_ints = [df.index.get_loc(label) for label in labels]
df.iloc[index_ints, [2, 4]]
```

#### Boolean Selection

The .loc indexer can also do boolean selection. For instance, if we are interested in finding all the rows where age is above 30 and return just the `food` and `score` columns we can do the following:

```
df.loc[df['age'] > 30, ['food', 'score']]
```

You can replicate this with `.iloc` but you cannot pass it a boolean series. You must convert the boolean Series into a numpy array like this:

```
df.iloc[(df['age'] > 30).values, [2, 4]]
```

---

#### Selecting all rows

It is possible to use `.loc/.iloc` for just column selection. You can select all the rows by using a colon like this:

```
df.loc[:, 'color':'score':2]
```

[image]

---

#### The indexing operator, `[]`, can slice can select rows and columns too but not simultaneously.

Most people are familiar with the primary purpose of the DataFrame indexing operator, which is to select columns. A string selects a single column as a Series and a list of strings selects multiple columns as a DataFrame.

```
df['food']

Jane          Steak
Nick           Lamb
Aaron         Mango
Penelope      Apple
Dean         Cheese
Christina     Melon
Cornelia      Beans
Name: food, dtype: object
```

Using a list selects multiple columns

```
df[['food', 'score']]
```

[image]

What people are less familiar with, is that, when slice notation is used, then selection happens by row labels or by integer location. This is very confusing and something that I almost never use but it does work.

```
df['Penelope':'Christina'] # slice rows by label
```

[image]

```
df[2:6:2] # slice rows by integer location
```

[image]

The explicitness of `.loc/.iloc` for selecting rows is highly preferred. The indexing operator alone is unable to select rows and columns simultaneously.

```
df[3:5, 'color']
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

---

### Selection by `.at` and `.iat`

Selection with `.at` is nearly identical to `.loc` but it only selects a single 'cell' in your DataFrame. We usually refer to this cell as a scalar value. To use `.at`, pass it both a row and column label separated by a comma.

```
df.at['Christina', 'color']
'black'
```

Selection with `.iat` is nearly identical to `.iloc` but it only selects a single scalar value. You must pass it an integer for both the row and column locations

```
df.iat[2, 5]
'FL'
```

Answer (score 32):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a', 'b', 'c'], 'B':[54, 67, 89]}, index=[100, 200, 300])

df

                        A   B
                100     a   54
                200     b   67
                300     c   89
In [19]:    
df.loc[100]

Out[19]:
A     a
B    54
Name: 100, dtype: object

In [20]:    
df.iloc[0]

Out[20]:
A     a
B    54
Name: 100, dtype: object

In [24]:    
df2 = df.set_index([df.index,'A'])
df2

Out[24]:
        B
    A   
100 a   54
200 b   67
300 c   89

In [25]:    
df2.ix[100, 'a']

Out[25]:    
B    54
Name: (100, a), dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's start with this small df:

```
import pandas as pd
import time as tm
import numpy as np
n=10
a=np.arange(0,n**2)
df=pd.DataFrame(a.reshape(n,n))
```

We'll so have

```
df
Out[25]: 
        0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
    0   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
    1  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
    2  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29
    3  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39
    4  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49
    5  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59
    6  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69
    7  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79
    8  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89
    9  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99
```

With this we have:

```
df.iloc[3,3]
Out[33]: 33

df.iat[3,3]
Out[34]: 33

df.iloc[:3,:3]
Out[35]: 
    0   1   2   3
0   0   1   2   3
1  10  11  12  13
2  20  21  22  23
3  30  31  32  33



df.iat[:3,:3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
   ... omissis ...
ValueError: At based indexing on an integer index can only have integer indexers
```

Thus we cannot use .iat for subset, where we must use .iloc only.

But let's try both to select from a larger df and let's check the speed ...

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Feb  7 09:58:39 2018

@author: Fabio Pomi
"""

import pandas as pd
import time as tm
import numpy as np
n=1000
a=np.arange(0,n**2)
df=pd.DataFrame(a.reshape(n,n))
t1=tm.time()
for j in df.index:
    for i in df.columns:
        a=df.iloc[j,i]
t2=tm.time()
for j in df.index:
    for i in df.columns:
        a=df.iat[j,i]
t3=tm.time()
loc=t2-t1
at=t3-t2
prc = loc/at *100
print('\nloc:%f at:%f prc:%f' %(loc,at,prc))

loc:10.485600 at:7.395423 prc:141.784987
```

So with .loc we can manage subsets and with .at only a single scalar, but .at is faster than .loc

:-)

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that for just accessing a column, `.loc` is about 7-10x slower than  `[]`:

**Test Script:**

```py
import os
import sys
from timeit import timeit

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def setup():
    arr = np.arange(0, 10 ** 2)
    return pd.DataFrame(arr.reshape(10, 10))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(f"Python: {sys.version}")
    print(f"Numpy: {np.__version__}")
    print(f"Pandas: {pd.__version__}")

    iters = 10000

    print(
        "[] Method:",
        timeit(
            "data = df[0]",
            setup="from __main__ import setup; df = setup()",
            number=iters,
        ),
    )
    print(
        ".loc() Method:",
        timeit(
            "data = df.loc[:, 0]",
            setup="from __main__ import setup; df = setup()",
            number=iters,
        ),
    )
```

**Output:**

```py
Python: 3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:48:03) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]
Numpy: 1.21.1
Pandas: 1.3.3
[] Method: 0.0923579000000001
.loc() Method: 0.6762988000000001
```