# Succinct way to access a single value from a Pandas DataFrame by index

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a DataFrame generated like so:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(seed=0)
df = pd.DataFrame(index=list('AB'), columns=list('CD'), data=np.random.randn(2,2))
```

which looks like

```
          C         D
A  1.764052  0.400157
B  0.978738  2.240893
```

and suppose I'd like to increase the value in row A, column C by 1. The way I've found to do this is:

```
df['C'][df.index.isin(['A'])] += 1
```

The left hand side seems quite verbose; I was hoping there might be a shorter way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `loc` directly on the col:

```
In [298]:
df['C'].loc['A'] += 1
df

Out[298]:
          C         D
A  2.764052  0.400157
B  0.978738  2.240893
```

or compound it by passing the row label as first arg on the df and select the col of interest after the comma:

```
In [300]:
df.loc['A','C'] += 1
df

Out[300]:
          C         D
A  2.764052  0.400157
B  0.978738  2.240893
```

Comment: All the solutions - using `loc`, `ix`, and `at` - seem to work for this example.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html):

```
np.random.seed(seed=0)
df = pd.DataFrame(index=list('AB'), columns=list('CD'), data=np.random.randn(2,2))

df.ix['A','C'] += 1
print (df)
          C         D
A  2.764052  0.400157
B  0.978738  2.240893
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.at` for accessing/setting scalars. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757389/loc-vs-iloc-vs-ix-vs-at-vs-iat) for a comparison of them.

```
df
Out: 
          C         D
A  1.764052  0.400157
B  0.978738  2.240893

df.at['A', 'C'] += 1

df
Out: 
          C         D
A  2.764052  0.400157
B  0.978738  2.240893
```