# How do I properly modify a cell in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a code where I'm modifying cells like this: `IBM["PNL"][2]=3`. It works, but it shows up a warning:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

From what I can read in the article, a proper way of modifying the value would had been `IBM.loc[2,"PNL"]=3`. However, that doesn't work for me, and it fails with following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-25-10debbad977d>", line 1, in <module>
    IBM_dataframe.loc[0,"PNL"]

  File "C:\Users\menkaur\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1310, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)

  File "C:\Users\menkaur\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 796, in _getitem_tuple
    return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)

  File "C:\Users\menkaur\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 922, in _getitem_lowerdim
    section = self._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)

  File "C:\Users\menkaur\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1482, in _getitem_axis
    self._has_valid_type(key, axis)

  File "C:\Users\menkaur\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1409, in _has_valid_type
    key = self._convert_scalar_indexer(key, axis)

  File "C:\Users\menkaur\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 196, in _convert_scalar_indexer
    return ax._convert_scalar_indexer(key, kind=self.name)

  File "C:\Users\menkaur\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\base.py", line 591, in _convert_scalar_indexer
    self._invalid_indexer('index', key)

  File "C:\Users\menkaur\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py", line 1284, in _invalid_indexer
    kind=type(key)))

TypeError: cannot do index indexing on <class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'> with these indexers [2] of <type 'int'>
```

Now, I'm confused

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `IBM` is a `pd.DataFrame`, `IBM["PNL"]` is a `pd.Series`.  The `[]` (square brackets) calls the `__getitem__` method and returns a series object.  You then call the `__getitem__` method on the series that was returned with `IBM["PNL"][2]`, namely the `[2]` part.  That's fine for now, even if a bit confusing.  The problem occurred when you tried to assign to it.  `IBM["PNL"][2] = 3` was telling `pandas` to assign to the 2nd element of the `pd.Series` `IBM["PNL"]` which is a view of the `"PNL"` column inside the `IBM` dataframe... dizzy yet?

So the answer is to assign directly to the `IBM` dataframe with `loc`, `iloc`, `at`, `iat`, or `set_value` using proper indexers.

---

[**`loc`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)
Allows you to pass 1-D arrays as indexers.  Arrays can be either slices (subsets) of the index or column, or they can be boolean arrays which are equal in length to the index or columns.

**Special Note:** when a scalar indexer is passed, `loc` can assign a new index or column value that didn't exist before.

```
# described by @ayhan
IBM.loc[IBM.index[2], 'PNL'] = 3
```

---

[**`iloc`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)
Similar to `loc` except with positions rather that index values.  However, you **cannot** assign new columns or indices.

```
# described by @ayhan
IBM.iloc[2, IBM.columns.get_loc('PNL')] = 3
```

---

[**`at`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html)
Works very similar to `loc` for scalar indexers.  **Cannot** operate on array indexers.  **Can!** assign new indices and columns

```
IBM.at[IBM.index[2], 'PNL'] = 3
```

---

[**`iat`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html)
Works similarly to `iloc`.  **Cannot** work in array indexers.  **Cannot!** assign new indices and columns.

```
IBM.iat[2, IBM.columns.get_loc('PNL')] = 3
```

---

[**`set_value`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_value.html)
Works very similar to `loc` for scalar indexers.  **Cannot** operate on array indexers.  **Can!** assign new indices and columns

```
IBM.set_value(IBM.index[2], 'PNL', 3)
```

---

[**`set_value` with `takable=True`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_value.html)
Works similarly to `iloc`.  **Cannot** work in array indexers.  **Cannot!** assign new indices and columns.

```
IBM.set_value(2, IBM.columns.get_loc('PNL'), 3, takable=True)
```

Comment: This would be very good at this question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757389/loc-vs-iloc-vs-ix-vs-at-vs-iat

Answer (score 4):

Now that `.ix` is deprecated, you have two alternatives:

```
IBM.loc[IBM.index[2], "PNL"] = 3
```

This is label based indexing. Since you need the label but you have the position, you use `IBM.index[2]` to return the label. Or,

```
IBM.iloc[2, IBM.columns.get_loc('PNL')] = 3
```

This is position based indexing. To get the position of column `PNL`, you use `get_loc`.

The error was because you were trying to use position based indexing for rows but label based indexing for columns. `.ix` was designed to handle such cases but it is deprecated. [Here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated) are details as noted by @jezrael.