# How to replace the value in the nth row of a given column in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

First, I create a pandas dataframe from a .csv file:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(infile1, sep=",", usecols=cols, header=0, names=["Timestamp","x"])
```

Second, I do `print df1.head()` which produces:

```
       Timestamp      x
0  1491894899989  15424
1  1491894899984  15424
2  1491894899979  15488
3  1491894899974  15488
4  1491894899969  15488
```

Then, doing `print int(df1.x.iloc[[0]].values)` yields `15424`.

Now, I want to replace the `iloc[[0]]` value for `x`.

The line `df1.x.iloc[[0]].values == 88` does not do the trick, since `print int(df1.x.iloc[[0]].values)` still yields `15424` rather than `88`.

**How to replace the value in the nth row of a given column in a pandas dataframe?**

Comment: There are a number of ways to assign a value at a particular cell. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43968774/190597.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try replacing the double equals sign (the comparison operator) with a single equals sign (the assignment operator):

```
df1.x.iloc[[0]].values = 88
```

Side note: in my testing, it is not necessary to wrap the row index `0` in list brackets in this case, nor is it necessary to assign the new value to `.values`. I get the same result as the line above with this:

```
df1.x.iloc[0] = 88
```

Maybe someone with more pandas experience can weigh in.

Runnable test case:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['asdf']*5})
df.col1.iloc[0] = 'jkl'
df
#    output:
#       col1
#    0   jkl
#    1  asdf
#    2  asdf
#    3  asdf
#    4  asdf
```