# Getting a scalar by integer location and column label (mixed indexing)

Tags: python, pandas

To get a scalar at integer location `0` and column label `'A'` in a data frame `df`, I do chained indexing: `df.iloc[0]['A']`. This works, but pandas documentation says that [chained indexing should be avoided](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy).

An alternative I could come up with is `df.iat[0, df.columns.get_loc('A')]`, which is just too much typing compared with the chained indexing. Is there a shorter way to do this?

*Note:* .ix indexer is deprecated.

**Example:**

`df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[10,20,30,40]}, index=[3,2,1,0])`

```
    A
------
3   10
2   20
1   30
0   40
```

The scalar at integer location `0` in column `A` is `10` and not `40`:
`df.iat[0, df.columns.get_loc('A')]`
Otuput: `10`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can refer to this other post on [**`loc`, `iloc`, `at`, `iat`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43968774/2336654)

---

*To answer your question directly:*
This is called mixed type indexing.  You want to access one dimension by position and the other by label.

To solve this problem, we need to translate either:

- the position into a label then use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) (or [`at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html)) for label indexing.
- the label into a position then use [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) (or [`iat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html)) for position indexing.

---

**Using [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)**

We get the label at the `0` position

```
df.loc[df.index[0], 'A']
```

Or

```
df.at[df.index[0], 'A']
```

Or

```
df.get_value(df.index[0], 'A')
```

---

**Using [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)**
We get the position of the label using `pd.Index.get_loc`

```
df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_loc('A')]
```

Or

```
df.iat[0, df.columns.get_loc('A')]
```

Or

```
df.get_value(0, df.columns.get_loc('A'), takable=True)
```

---

I also included examples of using [**`pd.DataFrame.get_value`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.get_value.html)

Comment: `df.at[df.index[0], 'A']` seems to be the shortest possible solution.

Comment: Logical but clever!

Answer (score 0):

Here's Pandas Official Guide on doing [Indexing with both Integer and Label](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#combining-positional-and-label-based-indexing). Hope this is helpful.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33837412)