# pandas can't update a cell value occasionally with method 'at'

Tags: python, pandas

Reference: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17127

### Code

```
def persistence(self):
    self.pd.to_csv(order_record_file_name, encoding='utf-8')

def _update_order_record(self, order_detail):
    order_pd_index = "%d" % order_detail.orderId
    if order_pd_index in self.pd.index.values:
        logging.info("Received order_detail:%s", order_detail.to_json())
        # of couse it runs here and i get he above logging, and then i update the cell value
        self.pd.at[order_pd_index, 'tradePrice'] = order_detail.tradePrice
        self.pd.at[order_pd_index, 'tradedVolume'] = order_detail.tradedVolume
        self.pd.at[order_pd_index, 'tradedAmount'] = order_detail.tradedAmount
        self.pd.at[order_pd_index, 'orderStatus'] = order_detail.orderStatus
       # here write it back to file
        self.persistence()
        # my temp solution is to check  whether the recorded value is the same as input
        for key in ['tradePrice', 'tradedVolume', 'tradedAmount', 'orderStatus']:
            if self.pd.loc[order_pd_index][key] != order_detail.__dict__[key]:
                logging.warn("%s not the same as record file" % key)
                self.pd.at[order_pd_index, key] = order_detail.__dict__[key]
                self.persistence()
            else:
                logging.info("key %s after updated is %s" % (key, str(self.pd.loc[order_pd_index][key])))
```

### Logs

#### Round 1  **good case**

*at 2017-07-26 09:21:00,913*

```
2017-07-26 09:21:00,913 139936711816960 StrategyOrderManagement.py,line 107     INFO: Received order_detail:{ "orderId": 1707260921000002148, "tradedAmount": 0.0, "userId": 95, "tradedVolume": 0, "orderStatus": 15, "strategyId": 40, "volumeOriginal": 11, "tradingDay": "20170726", "positionEffect": 0, "exchangeOrderId": 0, "createTime": 1501032060815, "hedgeFlag": 51, "orderPrice": 14910.0, "tradePrice": 0.0, "instrument": "CZCE.CF709", "bsFlag": -1}
2017-07-26 09:21:00,917 139936711816960 StrategyOrderManagement.py,line 123     INFO: key tradePrice after updated is 0.0
2017-07-26 09:21:00,918 139936711816960 StrategyOrderManagement.py,line 123     INFO: key tradedVolume after updated is 0.0
2017-07-26 09:21:00,919 139936711816960 StrategyOrderManagement.py,line 123     INFO: key tradedAmount after updated is 0.0
2017-07-26 09:21:00,920 139936711816960 StrategyOrderManagement.py,line 123     INFO: key orderStatus after updated is 15.0
```

#### Round 2  error case

*at 2017-07-26 09:21:02,704*

```
2017-07-26 09:21:02,704 139936711816960 StrategyOrderManagement.py,line 107     INFO: Received order_detail:{ "orderId": 1707260921000002148, "tradedAmount": 0.0, "userId": 95, "tradedVolume": 11,  "orderStatus": 19, "strategyId": 40, "volumeOriginal": 11, "tradingDay": "20170726", "positionEffect": 0, "exchangeOrderId": "2017072601552578", "createTime": 1501032060815, "hedgeFlag": 51, "orderPrice": 14910.0, "tradePrice": 14910.0, "instrument": "CZCE.CF709", "bsFlag": -1}
2017-07-26 09:21:02,707 139936711816960 StrategyOrderManagement.py,line 123     INFO: key tradePrice after updated is 14910.0
2017-07-26 09:21:02,707 139936711816960 StrategyOrderManagement.py,line 119      **WARNING: user dh515-02-1d strategy sz-strategy02-1d critial error:tradedVolume not the same as record file**
2017-07-26 09:21:03,858 139936711816960 StrategyOrderManagement.py,line 123     INFO: key tradedAmount after updated is 0.0
2017-07-26 09:21:03,859 139936711816960 StrategyOrderManagement.py,line 123     INFO: key orderStatus after updated is 19.0
```

### Problem description

Everyday my program does the same operation more than 1000 times, but failed less than 1 time per several days, and maybe no problem in months...  Sometimes on the field `tradedVolume`, sometimes the other filed such as `orderStatus`.

#### Output of `pd.show_versions()`

```
>>> pd.show_versions()

INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 2.7.5.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Linux
OS-release: 3.10.0-123.9.3.el7.x86_64
machine: x86_64
processor: x86_64
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: zh_CN.UTF-8

pandas: 0.18.1
nose: None
pip: 7.1.0
setuptools: 0.9.8
Cython: None
numpy: 1.11.1
scipy: None
statsmodels: None
xarray: None
IPython: None
sphinx: None
patsy: None
dateutil: 2.5.3
pytz: 2016.6.1
blosc: None
bottleneck: None
tables: None
numexpr: None
matplotlib: None
openpyxl: None
xlrd: None
xlwt: None
xlsxwriter: None
lxml: None
bs4: None
html5lib: None
httplib2: None
apiclient: None
sqlalchemy: None
pymysql: None
psycopg2: None
jinja2: None
boto: None
pandas_datareader: None
<details>
   # Paste the output here pd.show_versions() here
</details>
```

Answer (score 0):

`at` is depreciated, see [Loc vs. iloc vs. ix vs. at vs. iat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757389/loc-vs-iloc-vs-ix-vs-at-vs-iat)

Use `pd.set_value()` instead. In all applications I've used it in it has worked very reliably.

Comment: Hi,ic_fl2:
  Thanks for your reply. from your provided link I can't read `at` is depreciated but `set_value` is not intended for public use.  

  And confused me most is that when updating the same row, why one column cell failed but another successed?