# How set a particular cell value in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to set a value in panda dataframe.

```
ZEROS = np.zeros((4,4), dtype=np.int)

df = pd.DataFrame(ZEROS,  columns=['A1','B1','C1','D1'])
df.at[2,3] = 32
df
```

[image]

I don't want `NaN` for the entire column, the expected output is below:

Using numpy  I am able to set the value like below

```
ZEROS[1][3] = 44
```

output:

```
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 44],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

Comment: df.iloc[2,3]=32

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [**`pd.DataFrame.iat`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html) to reference and/or assign to the ordinal location of a single cell.

```
ZEROS = np.zeros((4,4), dtype=np.int)

df = pd.DataFrame(ZEROS,  columns=['A1','B1','C1','D1'])
df.iat[2,3] = 32
df

   A1  B1  C1  D1
0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0  32
3   0   0   0   0
```

---

You could also use `iloc` however, `iloc` can **also** take array like input.  This makes `iloc` more flexible but also requires more overhead.  Therefore, if it is only a single cell you want to change... use `iat`

---

*Also see this post for more information*

[**`loc`/`iloc`/`at`/`iat`/`set_value`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43968774/2336654)

Answer (score 11):

Use `iloc`:

```
df.iloc[2,3] = 32

print(df)
#   A1  B1  C1  D1
#0   0   0   0   0
#1   0   0   0   0
#2   0   0   0  32
#3   0   0   0   0
```

Or if you want to modify by index and column name, use `loc`:

```
df.loc[2, 'D1'] = 32
```