# Locate rows by particular label, found only in last multi-index level

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

After performing group-by, my new df has 3 level multindex. I need to access all rows with 'ZEBRA' labels; which is contained in the 3rd level index. I'm trying to use `df.loc` but unable to do so. I thought of iterating through the labels, but that will have to be a nested loop to make below; which makes me feel I'm not thinking along the right lines, there must be a much easier.

```
> indexlevel1_value1->indexlevel2_value1>indexlevel3_'stabilizer' 
> indexlevel1_value1->indexlevel2_value2>indexlevel3_'stabilizer' 
> indexlevel1_value1->indexlevel2_value3>indexlevel3_'stabilizer' 
> ................... 
> indexlevel2_value1->indexlevel2_value1>indexlevel3_'stabilizer'
```

This question looks close - [Selecting rows in a MultiIndex dataframe by index without losing any levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47886401/selecting-rows-in-a-multiindex-dataframe-by-index-without-losing-any-levels) but focused on first level index.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                             'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo',
                             'bar', 'foo', 'bar','foo', 
                              'bar','foo' ],
                         'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                                'two', 'two', 'one', 'three',
                                'two', 'three','two', 'two', 
                                'one', 'three'],
                         'C' : ['MR', 'ZEBRA', 'KID', 'ZEBRA', 
                                'MOS', 'ALPHA', 'ZULU', 'ZEBRA',
                               'TREE','PLANT', 'JOOMLA','ZEBRA',
                               'MOS','ZULU'],
                           'D' : np.random.randn(14)})  

grouped = df.groupby(['A', 'B','C'])
grouped.count()


| A   | B     | C      | D |
|-----|-------|--------|---|
| bar | one   | MOS    | 1 |
|     |       | ZEBRA  | 1 |
|     | three | ZEBRA  | 1 |
|     | two   | ALPHA  | 1 |
|     |       | JOOMLA | 1 |
|     |       | TREE   | 1 |
| foo | one   | MR     | 1 |
|     |       | ZULU   | 1 |
|     | three | PLANT  | 1 |
|     |       | ZEBRA  | 1 |
|     |       | ZULU   | 1 |
|     | two   | KID    | 1 |
|     |       | MOS    | 1 |
|     |       | ZEBRA  | 1 |

newdf= grouped.count()

newdf.loc[('bar','three','ZEBRA')]
#1
```

Desired:

```
| A   | B     | C     | D |
|-----|-------|-------|---|
| bar | one   | ZEBRA | 1 |
| bar | three | ZEBRA | 1 |
| foo | three | ZEBRA | 1 |
| foo | two   | ZEBRA | 1 |
```

Comment: You might find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927460/how-do-i-slice-or-filter-multiindex-dataframe-levels/53927461#53927461

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like using `axis` parameter in .loc:

```
df_out.loc(axis=0)[:, :, 'ZEBRA'].reset_index()
```

Output:

```
     A      B      C  D
0  bar    one  ZEBRA  1
1  bar  three  ZEBRA  1
2  foo  three  ZEBRA  1
3  foo    two  ZEBRA  1
```

Comment: See [docs on MultiIndex slicer](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
grouped[grouped.index.get_level_values(2) == 'ZEBRA'].reset_index()

     A      B      C  D
0  bar    one  ZEBRA  1
1  bar  three  ZEBRA  1
2  foo  three  ZEBRA  1
3  foo    two  ZEBRA  1
```

Alternate way: `grouped.query("C == 'ZEBRA'").reset_index()`

Comment: Thanks, I like your answers but I was fishing for a `loc` answer. So making that the solution