# How to define color of specific cell in pandas dataframe based on integer position (e.g., df.iloc[1,1]) with df.style?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

Is it possible to define a color of a specific cell in a pandas dataframe based on integer position like for instance df.iloc[1,1] with pandas styling? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html

Something like the following would be nice, but is not working.

```
def style_specific_cell(val):

    color = 'lightgreen'
    val.iloc[2, 8] = color
    return XYZ

df = df.style.applymap(style_specific_cell, subset=['Column1']
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`style.Styler.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) with helper `DataFrame` of styles:

```
def style_specific_cell(x):

    color = 'background-color: lightgreen'
    df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    df1.iloc[2, 8] = color
    return df1

df.style.apply(style_specific_cell, axis=None)
```

---

[image: pic]

Sample `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried your solution but unfortunately, the cell will not be colored in my case. I will add a screenshot to my question.

Comment: @blackrafi - sorry, few times was answer modify, check if use last version ;)

Comment: @blackrafi - need `color = 'background-color: green'`, not only `green`

Comment: One additional question: If I want to color several cells in a dataframe, how would this work?

Comment: @blackrafi - Do you think `df1.iloc[2, 3:] = color` ? Simply select by `iloc` what need coloring.

Comment: @blackrafi - I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47098873) should help explain more.

Comment: Thx, I used df5.iloc[[2,8], [2,2]] = color

Comment: @jezrael facing a similar issue but a bit more complicated, think you could take a look?