# Conditionally format cells in each column based on columns in another dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, pandas-styles

I have a dataframe that contains threshold values for 20+ elements that's formatted like so

df1:

|  | Li | Se | Be |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Upper | 30 | 40 | 10 |
| Lower | 10 | 5 | 1 |

I have another dataframe which contains values for those elements

df2:

|  | Li | Se | Be |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sample 1 | 50.8 | 100 | 20 |
| Sample 2 | -0.01 | 2 | -1 |

If the values in df2 are greater than the Upper threshold I want the background color of the cell in df2 be to red when it is written to an excel file. If the value is lower than the lower threshold I want the cell to be colored yellow.

So in the example, 50.8 background color should be red because 50.8 > 30.

I've done this before when comparing a single value like so

```
df.style.apply(lambda x: 'background-color : red' if x>=value else '')
```

But I'm lost on how to apply it column wise based on the columns in df1

Comment: You're trying to color both dataframes based on df2? Just color df1 based on df2. the other way around?

Comment: @HenryEcker trying to color df2 based on df1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html#numpy-select) to compare dataframes and set results for conditions:

```
def bounded_highlights(df):
    conds = [df > df1.loc['Upper'], df < df1.loc['Lower']]
    labels = ['background-color:red', 'background-color: yellow']
    return np.select(conds, labels, default='')


df2.style.apply(bounded_highlights, axis=None)
```

[image: styled df2]

DataFrames and Imports (slightly modified df2 so not all are highlighted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Li': {'Upper': 30, 'Lower': 10},
                    'Se': {'Upper': 40, 'Lower': 5},
                    'Be': {'Upper': 10, 'Lower': 1}})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Li': {'Sample 1': 50.8, 'Sample 2': -0.01},
    'Se': {'Sample 1': 100, 'Sample 2': 6},
    'Be': {'Sample 1': 9, 'Sample 2': -1}
})
```

modified `df2`:

```
             Li   Se  Be
Sample 1  50.80  100   9
Sample 2  -0.01    6  -1
```

How the `np.select` code works:

```
conds = [df2 > df1.loc['Upper'], df2 < df1.loc['Lower']]
labels = ['background-color:red', 'background-color: yellow']
styles = np.select(conds, labels, default='')
```

`conds`:

```
[             Li     Se     Be
Sample 1   True   True  False
Sample 2  False  False  False,
              Li     Se     Be
Sample 1  False  False  False
Sample 2   True  False   True]
```

`styles` labels are applied based on the `True` values in `conds`:

```
[['background-color:red' 'background-color:red' '']
 ['background-color: yellow' '' 'background-color: yellow']]
```

Comment: I think this should work. It runs without issue but when I print to excel the cells aren't colored. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know how you're sending to excel but you'll need to pass the _styler_ to excel not the dataframe `df2.style.apply(bounded_highlights, axis=None).to_excel(...)`

Comment: This worked but I had to edit the function in order for it to return a df with the same cols and index as the target df instead of an array

Answer (score 1):

You can do as suggested here: [How to define color of specific cell in pandas dataframe based on integer position (e.g., df.iloc[1,1]) with df.style?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52887800/2988730). The basic idea is to make a dataframe of styles you want to use, and apply that:

```
styles = pd.DataFrame('', index=df2.index, columns=df2.columns)
styles[df2 > df1.loc['Upper']] = 'background-color : red'
df2.style.apply(styles, axis=None)
```

This is similar to what [@Henry Ecker suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68459819/2988730), except it does not use `np.select`, instead applying the conditions manually.