# Use .apply to conditionally color specific cell in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I have a pandas dataframe with a few columns. I am trying to color the cells in one of the columns and I have been partially successful so far.

In the column `color_me` I want to:

1. For all the rows but the last one, I will be coloring according to a specific scale
2. In the last row of that column (therefore, just one cell), I want to color based on another scale. It is the 9th row of that column.

I was able to do 1., but I am failing to do 2. I don't know how to highlight just one specific cell if I have to put a conditional on which color it should be having.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'metric': ['metric0', 'metric1', 'metric2', 'metric3', 'metric4', 'metric5', 'metric6', 'metric7', 'metric8', 'metric9'],
                  'column1': [80, 12, 110, 100.2, 39, 29, 48, 78, 93, 100.8],
                  'color_me': [89, 102, 43, 112, 70, 38, 80, 110, 93, 100.3]})

def highlight_SLA(series):
    green = 'background-color: lightgreen'
    yellow = 'background-color: yellow'
    pink = 'background-color: pink'
    return [green if value <= 90 else yellow if value <100 else pink for value in series]

def highlight_specific_cell(series):
    green = 'background-color: lightgreen'
    yellow = 'background-color: yellow'
    pink = 'background-color: pink'
    return [green if value >= 100.2 else yellow if value >100 else pink for value in series]


slice_SLA = ['color_me']

slice_SLA_index = ['color_me'][9]


(df.style

     .apply(highlight_SLA, subset = slice_SLA)
 
     .apply(highlight_SLA_availability_index, subset = slice_SLA_index)
       )
```

The second `apply` doesn't work as I wanted. It is supposed to give a green background to the that has a value of `100.3`.

Should I select its subset in another way? It seems that `slice_SLA_index = ['color_me'][9]` is not the way to do it, but I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Hi, Henry! Thanks for the tip! I updated the question to include a sample DataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intent of the question is to code with the understanding that we want to set a special color as the background color only for specific rows of specific columns. For the columns that we pass the specific columns, we create a list of background colors by condition, create a blank series, and then set that color where we want it to be placed. Adapt that style to the data frame in the original. The original of this code was changed from this answer to a series to accommodate [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52887800/how-to-define-color-of-specific-cell-in-pandas-dataframe-based-on-integer-positi).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.randint(50, 150, 4) for _ in range(10)], columns=['A','B','C','D'])

def highlight_SLA(series):
    green = 'background-color: lightgreen'
    yellow = 'background-color: yellow'
    pink = 'background-color: pink'
    return [green if value <= 90 else yellow if value <100 else pink for value in series]

def highlight_specific_cell(x):
    idx = 9
    green = 'background-color: lightgreen'
    yellow = 'background-color: yellow'
    pink = 'background-color: pink'
    color = [green if v >= 100.2 else yellow if v >100 else pink for v in x]
    xx = pd.Series('', index=x.index)
    xx.loc[idx] = color[idx]
    return xx

slice_SLA = ['A']
slice_SLA_index = ['B']

(df.style.apply(highlight_SLA, subset=slice_SLA)
.apply(highlight_specific_cell, subset=slice_SLA_index))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, @r-beginners! This worked as I wanted. I just had to change the `slice_SLA_index = ['B']` to `['A']`. If it is possible, I would like to ask a few follow-up questions to better understand what is happening. On the line `xx = pd.Series('', index=x.index)`. 1) What is the `''`doing? 2) `index=x.index` brings the row number? 3) What is `xx.loc[idx]` doing? 4) Is the `color=[green if etc.]` a function inside a function? 5) When the `highlight_specific_cell` function is running, is it correct to say that `xx` is replaced by column `['B']`?

Comment: Sorry for the insufficient explanation.
1) I am creating an empty series.
2) Row number. Indexes are set on the series.
3)We are positioning a specific background color for the created series.
4)We make a color determination and create a list for the target column, ['B'].
5)Your understanding of that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to modify only specific rows in addition to columns is to make the `subset` more restrictive by indexing both axes. The standard approach is to use an [IndexSlice](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html).

Instead of:

```
slice_SLA_index = ['color_me'][9]
```

Make a 2D [IndexSlice](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html):

```
slice_SLA_index = pd.IndexSlice[9, 'color_me']
```

Here the `9` is the row index number, and `color_me` is the column name, though The `subset` can be expanded if needed.

```
slice_SLA = ['color_me']
slice_SLA_index = pd.IndexSlice[9, 'color_me']

(
    df.style
        .apply(highlight_SLA, subset=slice_SLA)
        .apply(highlight_specific_cell, subset=slice_SLA_index)
)
```

[image: Styled table output with index 9 in column 'color_me' styled with highlight_specific_cell rules]

*Notice that index 9 `color_me` is green due to the `highlight_specific_cell` rules rather than pink (`highlight_SLA`) rules.

---

The `subset` can be modified using standard `loc` indexing rules. For example, rows 7-9 in `column1` and `color_me` could be `subset` in the following way:

```
slice_SLA = ['color_me']
slice_SLA_index = pd.IndexSlice[7:9, ['column1', 'color_me']]

(
    df.style
        .apply(highlight_SLA, subset=slice_SLA)
        .apply(highlight_specific_cell, subset=slice_SLA_index)
)
```

[image: Styled table output with index 7:9 in columns 'column1' and 'color_me' styled with highlight_specific_cell rules]

---

As a general improvement [np.select](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) is a more common solution to multi-condition mappings than a list comprehension:

```
import numpy as np

def highlight_SLA(series):
    green = 'background-color: lightgreen'
    yellow = 'background-color: yellow'
    pink = 'background-color: pink'
    return np.select(
        condlist=[series <= 90, series < 100],
        choicelist=[green, yellow],
        default=pink
    )


def highlight_specific_cell(series):
    green = 'background-color: lightgreen'
    yellow = 'background-color: yellow'
    pink = 'background-color: pink'
    return np.select(
        condlist=[series >= 100.2, series > 100],
        choicelist=[green, yellow],
        default=pink
    )
```