pandas apply style to one row based on comparison of two rows
guys I have tried official example. Found something on Internet, but still cannot get it right.



index
2000
2001




price
1
2


price_real
1.5
1.8



in above by table, I wanna run following test:
if df.loc['price_real'] > df.loc['price']:
if true, mark df.loc['price'] with  'background-color: green'
df.style.apply(lambda x: ['background-color: green']*len(df_s) if \
(x.loc['stock_price_real'] > x.loc['stock_price']) else ['background-color: none']*len(df_s), \
axis = 0)
above by code partially works, but I can't force it to mark only df.loc['price'] row. I tried to add subset=pd.IndexSlice[['stock_price'], :], but it ends up by error.

There is example of my program, but it marks also all rows below or above.
Any suggestion, please?
only df.loc['price'] row marked if true

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71359558/use-apply-to-conditionally-color-specific-cell-in-pandas-dataframe

Unfortunately, not. Whenever I write subset, it ends up by error. target=pd.IndexSlice['stock_price', df_s.columns]
All these examples always deal with single row comparison. It is also suggested to use np.selectinstead of list comprehension.

This should work, we iterate over columns and choose only stock_price row to be colored if condition is True :
df.style.apply(
    lambda x: ["background-color: green" 
               if (x.name == "stock_price" and x[col] < df.loc["stock_price_real", col]) 
               else "" 
               for col in x.index],
    axis=1)

minimal example :
import pandas as pd

data = {"2000": [1, 1.5], "2001": [2, 1.8]}
index = ["stock_price", "stock_price_real"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index)

df.style.apply(
    lambda x: ["background-color: green" 
               if (x.name == "stock_price" and x[col] < df.loc["stock_price_real", col]) 
               else "" 
               for col in x.index],
    axis=1)



thanks chief, that is exactly what I tried to achieve.
