# What is the difference between df.iloc[[i]] and df.iloc[i]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is the difference between `df.iloc[[i]]` and `df.iloc[i]`?

I recognize `df.iloc[[i]]` represents matrix's `i`-row (parallel shape), but
`de.iloc[i]` represents matrix's `i`-row  as like Vertical shape.

I wonder why `de.iloc[i]` shows vertical shape.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas loc vs. iloc vs. at vs. iat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757389/pandas-loc-vs-iloc-vs-at-vs-iat)

Comment: That is a different question asking about the difference between 3 methods. This question is asking about the way one method interprets different types of inputs.

Answer (score 1):

A different object type is returned in each instance.

When you pass a scalar integer `[0]` it returns a *Series* object.

When you pass a list of integers `[[0]]` (this is a list of length 1) it returns a *DataFrame* object.

You can see for yourself by running:
`type(df.iloc[i])` vs `type(df.iloc[[i]])`.

See [pandas.DataFrame.iloc documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html).