# How to overwrite a value with another one in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have prepared the dataframe

|  | Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a1 | temp |
| 1 | b1 | temp |
| 2 | c1 | temp |

I prepared the Col2 with `df['Col2'] = 'temp'`

I would like to overwrite **only Col2 row0**, and tried following code.

`df['Col2'][0] = 'a'`

However I got an below error.

**IndexError: list index out of range**

Comment: `df.at[0, 'Col2']` or `df.iat[0, 1]`. Cf [pandas loc vs. iloc vs. at vs. iat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757389/pandas-loc-vs-iloc-vs-at-vs-iat).

Comment: You could also use `loc` try: `df.loc[0,'Col2']='new_Value'` to get 1st element of col1.

Comment: ```df['Col2'][0] = 'a'``` works for me

Comment: Your code df['Col2'][0] = 'a' works for me. The syntax is perfectly fine. So, one possible reason is your row index doesn't contain 0. In this case, you can use: df['Col2'].iloc[0] = 'a' if you want to modify for the first row.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using iloc function

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1, 2, 3], 'col2':['temp', 'temp', 'temp']})
df.iloc[2:, 1:] = 'R'
```

supposed to work.

Note - there are many other ways too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to index by row first, then column using the .loc accessor:

```
df.loc[0, 'Col2'] = 'a'
```