# Selecting data from a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have defined a pandas DataFrame, given the number of rows (index) and columns. I perform a series of operations and store the data in such DataFrame. The code that makes this operation is the next one:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

sens_fac = [0.8, 1, 1.2]

A = 13;
B = 5;
C = 7/2;
D = 3*1.2;
par = [A,B,C,D]
data = pd.DataFrame(index=range(len(sens_fac)),columns=range(len(par)))

for i in range(len(par)):
    factors = [1, 1, 1, 1]
    for j in range(len(sens_fac)):
        factors[i] = sens_fac[j]
        print(factors)
        x=25
        t1 = np.log(x)**math.sin(x/(A*factors[0]))
        t2 = (B*factors[1])*math.sqrt(x)
        t3 = (factors[2]*C)**math.exp(1/x)
        t4 = x/(factors[3]*D)*2
        res = t1 + t2 + t3 + t4
        data[i][j] = res
```

The problem is when I try to select a specific element of such DataFrame. For example, if I print data, it would be a DataFrame of **3 rows and 4 columns**. But when I try to select the element of the third row and fourth column (`data[2][3]`), I get an error. On the other hand, if I select the element as`data[3][2]`, it gives me the number I am looking for, but I understand that `data[3][2]` would be the fourth row and third column, which is an element that does not exist.

Comment: `data.at[2,3]` is what you want, as accessing directly is columns first in DataFrames.

Comment: @asimoneau but I don't understand, the first number between `[]` refers to rows and the second number between `[]` refers to columns, isn't it?

Comment: It's confusing because you're using numerical labels. `data['a']` would be the column `'a'` of your DataFrame. As such, `data[2][3]` returns the element index 3 of the column 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data frame values can be accessed using explicit indexing(loc), implicit indexing (iloc).
To be more clear: suppose column 3 has the name 'qwe', and the index of row 2 will be 'c'. This is called explicit reference to indexes.

`data.loc['c', 'qwe']`

Implicitly , you can apply like this:

`data.iloc[2, 3]`

But, if you will use a slice. Then with explicit indexing, there will be one more value, since with explicit indexing, the slice occurs inclusive.

```
print(data.loc[:2, 3])
print(data.iloc[:2, 3])
"""
0    49.0406
1    45.5684
2    43.2536
Name: 3, dtype: object
0    49.0406
1    45.5684
Name: 3, dtype: object
"""
```

Since you have indexes (rows) in strict numbering, using an explicit and implicit index will lead to the same result.

```
print(data.loc[2, 3])#43.2535547215997
print(data.iloc[2, 3])#43.2535547215997
```

iloc, loc and at, iat the difference is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757389/pandas-loc-vs-iloc-vs-at-vs-iat)

For single values, it is assumed that faster at, iat.