# Researchpy : Warning in the example of summary_cont() page

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The researchpy's [summary_cont() page](https://researchpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/summary_cont_documentation.html) there is an example and it is given as;

```py
import numpy, pandas, researchpy

numpy.random.seed(12345678)

df = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.random.randint(10, size= (100, 2)),
                  columns= ['healthy', 'non-healthy'])
df['tx'] = ""
df['tx'].iloc[0:50] = "Placebo"
df['tx'].iloc[50:101] = "Experimental"

df['dose'] = ""
df['dose'].iloc[0:26] = "10 mg"
df['dose'].iloc[26:51] = "25 mg"
df['dose'].iloc[51:76] = "10 mg"
df['dose'].iloc[76:101] = "25 mg"
```

produces warning

```
summury_cont.py:8: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df['tx'].iloc[0:50] = "Placebo"
```

This asks to see this [page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy)

Converting into this

```
df.loc[:, ('tx')].iloc[0:50] = "Placebo"
```

It still produces the same warning. What is the correct way of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Values are assigned as shown below. Row indexes on the left, column names on the right. Explicit 'loc' indexing is used. You can see the difference between explicit and implicit 'iloc' indexing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72235641/selecting-data-from-a-pandas-dataframe/72240640#72240640)

```
import numpy, pandas

numpy.random.seed(12345678)

df = pandas.DataFrame(data = numpy.random.randint(10, size= (100, 2)),
                  columns= ['healthy', 'non-healthy'])

df['tx'] = ""
df.loc[0:50, 'tx'] = "Placebo"
df.loc[50:101, 'tx'] = "Experimental"

df['dose'] = ""
df.loc[0:26, 'dose'] = "10 mg"
df.loc[26:51, 'dose'] = "25 mg"
df.loc[51:76, 'dose'] = "10 mg"
df.loc[76:101, 'dose'] = "25 mg"
print(df)
```

Output

```
    healthy  non-healthy            tx   dose
0         3            2       Placebo  10 mg
1         4            1       Placebo  10 mg
2         0            1       Placebo  10 mg
3         8            2       Placebo  10 mg
4         6            6       Placebo  10 mg
..      ...          ...           ...    ...
95        8            5  Experimental  25 mg
96        8            3  Experimental  25 mg
97        4            0  Experimental  25 mg
98        4            3  Experimental  25 mg
99        6            9  Experimental  25 mg
```