# pandas.dataframe.iloc[[i, j, k]] returns rows with the wrong index

Tags: python, pandas

When trying to use a list of indices to get a subset of the dataframe, it's puzzling to see the `.iloc` returns rows with the wrong index. When trying `.loc`, it returns rows with the correct index.

Can anyone explain to me why the `.iloc` returned rows of unexpected index?

```
df = pdTools.LoadSDF(infile, removeHs=False, sanitize=False)
print(df.shape) 
>>(499997, 13)

print(df.iloc[[8888,10000, 20000, 77777, 400000, 450000]])
>>         idnumber 
>> 8888    Z2885081048           
>> 10000   Z2893553470          
>> 20000   Z2906211876           
>> **77778**   Z2996496294         
>> **400003**  Z4897443126            
>> **450003**  Z5129522901
```

I expect it to return rows of the specified indices as shown below.

```
print(df.loc[[8888,10000, 20000, 77777, 400000, 450000]])
>>          idnumber
>> 8888    Z2885081048  
>> 10000   Z2893553470  
>> 20000   Z2906211876  
>> 77777   Z2996496291  
>> 400000  Z4897436078  
>> 450000  Z5129522881
```

Comment: Welcome. As a lot of being puzzled comes from not reading the docs, it is highly recommended to read the couple pages of loc/iloc pandas documentation in order to understand their difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Key concept

- `.iloc[]` finds location assuming a HYPOTHETICAL 0-based consecutive incremental index (i.e. [0, 1, 2, ...])
- `.loc[]` finds location based on the content of the ACTUAL index

In other words, while your index seems to be a sequence of consecutive positive numbers, if it is actually not 0-based or skipped some number in between, `.iloc[]` will differ from `.loc[]`.

In your case, it is likely that some value is skipped between index 20000 and 77778, and another two values skipped between 77778 and 400003. This is why the selected indices were shifted slightly.

This can be easily understood by the following simplified example:

### Example

**data**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={"col0": ["A0", "A1", "A2", "A4", "A6"]},
    index=[0, 1, 2, 4, 6]
)
#   col0
# 0   A0
# 1   A1
# 2   A2
# 4   A4
# 6   A6
```

**Use .iloc[] to select the first 4 rows**

```
df.iloc[[0,1,2,3]]
#   col0
# 0   A0
# 1   A1
# 2   A2
# 4   A4
```

**Equivalent selection using .loc[]**

Note that `[0,1,2,4]` stands for the actual value in the index, with index `4` actually being the 3rd element (counting up from 0st).

```
df.loc[[0,1,2,4]]
#   col0
# 0   A0
# 1   A1
# 2   A2
# 4   A4
```

**wrong**

```
df.loc[[0,1,2,3]]
# KeyError: '[3] not in index'
```

### Additional Reading

For a comprehensive understanding about indexing and data selection in pandas, I personally recommend the following article/post:

- [Indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html)
- [pandas loc vs. iloc vs. at vs. iat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757389/pandas-loc-vs-iloc-vs-at-vs-iat)

Test environment

- `Python` (from `conda`): `3.12.2`
- `Pandas`: `2.1.4`
- `OS`: Debian 12 (x86-64)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this. I presumed the dataframe index is consecutive since it's reading from the input sdf file. It's possible that some entries were skipped due to sanitization problem.