# Issue with Assigning NaNs in Process Function for Mathematical Operations on Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm encountering an issue with assigning NaNs while performing mathematical operations on a Pandas DataFrame in Python. I have a function `process_mr` that is intended to process mathematical rules specified in each equation column of the DataFrame. For instance, a mathematical rule might be represented as "A = B + C + D", where A, B, C, and D are column names in the DataFrame, and the operation involves addition.

The function `process_mr` is supposed to iterate over the DataFrame, evaluate the mathematical expressions for each row, and store the results in two separate DataFrames: `subtraction_df` for subtraction results and `boolean_df` for boolean evaluation results.

Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
# Function to perform mathematical operations on DataFrame columns
def process_mr(df, equation_column, subtraction_df, boolean_df):
    if ' = ' in equation_column:
        equation_column2 = equation_column.replace(' = ',' == ')
        lhs, rhs = equation_column2.split('==')
    elif '<=' in equation_column:
        equation_column2 = equation_column
        lhs, rhs = equation_column2.split('<=')
    elif '>=' in equation_column:
        equation_column2 = equation_column
        lhs, rhs = equation_column.split('>=')
    
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        lhs_list = [x.strip() for x in lhs.split('+')] if '+' in lhs else lhs.split()
        rhs_list = [x.strip() for x in rhs.split('+')] if '+' in rhs else rhs.split()

        # Insert DataFrame values into lhs_list and rhs_list
        lhs_val_list = [row.loc[col] if col != '100' else 100 for col in lhs_list] 
        rhs_val_list = [row.loc[col] if col != '100' else 100 for col in rhs_list]

        # Convert all elements to float
        lhs_val_list = [float(x) for x in lhs_val_list] 
        rhs_val_list = [float(x) for x in rhs_val_list]

        if (np.all(np.isnan(lhs_val_list))) or (all(x is None for x in lhs_val_list)) or (np.all(np.isnan(rhs_val_list)) or (all(x is None for x in rhs_val_list))):
            # Assign NaN where a Math Check would have been performed
            subtraction_df[equation_column][index] = np.nan
            boolean_df[equation_column][index] = np.nan
            continue  # Skips to next iteration
        else:
            # Assign 0 to any NaNs that exist for lhs_val_list and rhs_val_list (NaN can't be used in     a calculation)
            lhs_val_list = [x if not np.isnan(x) else 0 for x in lhs_val_list]
            rhs_val_list = [x if not np.isnan(x) else 0 for x in rhs_val_list]
            # Perform subtraction operation for math rule and assign the result in subtraction_df
            subtraction_df[equation_column][index] = np.sum(lhs_val_list) - np.sum(rhs_val_list)

            # Evaluate math rule and store the result in boolean_df
            row_vals = df.loc[index]
            boolean_df[equation_column][index] = eval(equation_column2, row_vals.to_dict())

    return subtraction_df, boolean_df

# Loop through equation columns and perform the operation
for col in new_mr_columns_list:
    process_mr(df, col, subtraction_df, boolean_df)
```

Using the above function and code, I expected this to produce fewer false values in boolean_df due to NaN assignment before evaluation. However, it produces more False values than I know to be correct. What errors or issues do you see in the code above? Thanks.

Comment: Can u share example table, and can u show your code's result and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

here are some general remarks :

- Try to use `.iat` or `.at` instead of `.loc`, you will be faster here is a link about [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757389/pandas-loc-vs-iloc-vs-at-vs-iat)
- Using **eval** for evaluating boolean expressions can be risky and inefficient, especially within a loop. You should use something else
- I think you can simplify your code, there are too many list comprehension which makes more complex and subject of errors