# Pandas dataframe and to_numeric: select column by index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numeric

The question is probaly extremely dumb, but i hurt my brain figuring out what to do

There is a `pd.dataframe` with N columns. I need to select some columns, referring by index of a column, then convert all values to numeric and rewrite that column in my `dataframe`

I've done it by column name reference (like `df['a'] = pd.to_numeric(df['a'])` but stuck with indices (like `df[1] = pd.to_numeric(df[1])`

What is the right way in this situation to `dataframe` column referencing? (python 2.7)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for selecting columns and then [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({1:['1','2','3'],
                   2:[4,5,6],
                   3:[7,8,9],
                   4:['1','3','5'],
                   5:[5,3,6],
                   6:['7','4','3']})

print (df)
   1  2  3  4  5  6
0  1  4  7  1  5  7
1  2  5  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  3

print (df.dtypes)
1    object
2     int64
3     int64
4    object
5     int64
6    object
dtype: object

print (df.columns)
Int64Index([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], dtype='int64')
```

```
cols = [1,4,6]    
df.iloc[:, cols] = df.iloc[:, cols].apply(pd.to_numeric)

print (df)
   1  2  3  4  5  6
0  1  4  7  1  5  7
1  2  5  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  3

print (df.dtypes)
1    int64
2    int64
3    int64
4    int64
5    int64
6    int64
dtype: object
```

If columns are `strings`, not `int` (but it looks like `int`) add `''` to numbers in `list` `cols`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'1':['1','2','3'],
                   '2':[4,5,6],
                   '3':[7,8,9],
                   '4':['1','3','5'],
                   '5':[5,3,6],
                   '6':['7','4','3']})

#print (df)

#print (df.dtypes)

print (df.columns)
Index(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'], dtype='object')

#add `''`
cols = ['1','4','6']

#1. loc: only label based access
# df.loc[:, cols] = df.loc[:, cols].apply(pd.to_numeric)

#2. iloc: for index based access
# cols = [1,4,6]
# df.iloc[:, cols].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

---

```
print (df)
   1  2  3  4  5  6
0  1  4  7  1  5  7
1  2  5  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  3

print (df.dtypes)
1    int64
2    int64
3    int64
4    int64
5    int64
6    int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you, it looks good. But is there a way to reference column with non-int header with int? I mean, referencing 6th column in `Index(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', 'k'], dtype='object')` with `cols = [6]` ?

Comment: Yes, you can use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) - so 6. columns is `df.iloc[:,5]` (python count from 0)

Comment: For future readers, `ix` has been deprecated. You can use `iloc` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the following post out
[Is .ix() always better than .loc() and .iloc() since it is faster and supports integer and label access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27667759/is-ix-always-better-than-loc-and-iloc-since-it-is-faster-and-supports-i)

A must
[Different choice of Indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing)