# How to change one dataframe column values based on a sibling column values?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Let's say I have a dataframe with columns: "Date, Price".

I wish to achieve this:
If the value of the date in the "Date" column of the dataframe falls between April and October, I want to create a new column:

```py
df['Price_new'] = df[Price] + 0.01
```

And if it falls between November and March:

```py
df['Price_new'] = df['Price'] + 0.12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to have your dates in `datetime` format. If they're not already datetimes, you can convert them with `pd.to_datetime`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['17-2-21', '1-4-21', '21-6-21', '15-9-21', '17-2-22'], 'Price': [10.2, 12.5, 7.0, 3.8, 8.8]})
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df
```

| index | Date | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-02-17 | 10.2 |
| 1 | 2021-01-04 | 12.5 |
| 2 | 2021-06-21 | 7.0 |
| 3 | 2021-09-15 | 3.8 |
| 4 | 2022-02-17 | 8.8 |

Then you can use `apply` in a similar way than [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41968619/15032126):

```
df.loc[(df['Date'].dt.month >= 4) & (df['Date'].dt.month <= 10),'Price_new'] = df.loc[(df['Date'].dt.month >= 4) & (df['Date'].dt.month <= 10),'Price'].apply(lambda x: x + 0.01)
df.loc[(df['Date'].dt.month <= 3) | (df['Date'].dt.month >= 11),'Price_new'] = df.loc[(df['Date'].dt.month <= 3) | (df['Date'].dt.month >= 11),'Price'].apply(lambda x: x + 0.12)
df
```

| index | Date | Price | Price_new |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-02-17 | 10.2 | 10.32 |
| 1 | 2021-01-04 | 12.5 | 12.62 |
| 2 | 2021-06-21 | 7.0 | 7.01 |
| 3 | 2021-09-15 | 3.8 | 3.81 |
| 4 | 2022-02-17 | 8.8 | 8.92 |